# Odoo - Hide a group or page in inherited view without name

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

I am trying inherit `base.user_groups_view` and `base.view_users_form` to hide some information which is not useful in my case.

**base.view_users_form**

I want to hide `Preferences` tab completely but this page have a string and doesn't have a name attribute that's why when i try to find out this page it says `cannot locate in parent view` and if i try to search using `string` attribute it says `View inheritance may not use attribute 'string' as a selector.`

**base.view_users_form**

Same a above when i try to hide Application spearator it says `View inheritance may not use attribute 'string' as a selector.`

How to hide these when we are in inherited view

**Edit**

I am using Odoo 10 Enterprise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In odoo 9 it is impossible to use 'string' in xpath expressions. In your case you should use an index. For example:

```
<xpath expr="//page[3]">
    <!-- your code -->
</xpath>
```

This will search the third element that is a page in your view.

You could visit: [xpath_string](https://github.com/Yenthe666/Odoo_Samples/issues/1) for more information.

I hope this help you!

Comment: Sorry i didn't mention but i am using odoo 10e

Comment: Maybe in odoo 10e is deprecated too. I personally do not like it, but I think that if you don't have other distinctive attribute you should use the index.